# Are \choose and \align incompatible?

Tags: amsmath, align

I ran across a strange warning when trying to use the math command `\choose` inside the `amsmath` package's `\align*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
{n \choose k}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwidthdelims;                           \frac or \genfrac should be used instead

The document still compiles and produces perfectly fine output.  But what is causing this warning?  And is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: It seems amsmath doesn't recognize her own grandfather: `\choose` is short for `\atopwithdelims()`, and `\atopwithdelims` is a TeX primitive. So in that light the word ‘foreign‘ seems quite strange; after all, amsmath, like any other TeX macro package, is built on TeX primitives.

Comment: @morbusg "Foreign" refers to the syntax of `\choose` that doesn't fit with the standard syntax of LaTeX commands.

Comment: @egreg: if it means that, it'd be nice if it read like that, but as it stands, it reads (emphasis mine): “Warning: **Foreign command** `\atopwithdelims`…”.

Comment: @morbusg Unfortunately it's not `\choose` that triggers the warning, but only `\atopwithdelims`. All the part dealing with this warning should be rewritten if it wanted to cope with a variety of foreign commands.

Comment: LaTeX is just full of surprises, isn't it?

Comment: @egreg: you just said “foreign commands” on purpose, didn't you? `:-D` even though you just said it in perfect form in the previous comment: “doesn't fit with the standard syntax of LaTeX commands”.

Comment: @morbusg I was referring to foreign commands based on `\over` and friends. It's easy to say `\renewcommand{\choose}{\primfrac{choose}}`, but the message would say to use `\frac` or `\genfrac` anyway; I would prefer a message telling about `\binom`. That's why I said that this part should be rewritten. OTOH, the documentation is quite neat in telling to use `\frac`, `\binom` and so on.

Comment: @egreg: aaaah, ok, I see.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Do not use `{n \choose k}` in LaTeX (it is a plain TeX command).  The recommended way in LaTeX is `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble and then `\binom{n}{k}`.  (You have then also `\tbinom` and `\dbinom` for text and display styles also.)

Comment: but this doesn't explain _why_ ... the problem is that knuth's format is evil on several levels.  the worst is that it forces on us the ghastly \mathchoice, which leads us into problems about multiple evaluation of everything.  the practical thing is that it sticks out like a sore thumb from the rest of the syntax of latex, to the extent that it gives headaches to the writers of translators.  (i've heard knuth say, in a talk, that he can't see why people care, since it's trivially easy to edit tex source to produce a version to do *anything*.  ha!)

Answer (score 12):

Simple answer: Don't use `\choose`, or don't use `amsmath`, or live with the warnings.

There is a long explanation of why this kind of construct is deprecated in the document [technote.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/technote.pdf) which is part of the amsmath docs, in the section "4 Why do \over, \atop, \above [. . . withdelims] give a warning when I add the amsmath package?"